# Any way to mass sell all my steam trading cards?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I have a large number of steam trading cards and for me they are just filling up my inventory, I have no interest in doing anything with them except selling them. Is there any way to mass sell all my steam trading cards?

Note that this is not an invitation to add me on steam for trading that system is too slow for me and not worth my time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Having just looked into this same challenge, Steam Inventory Helper (the originally-linked-to answer) has been [reported for spying on its users](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/70xofs/warning_trusted_steam_inventory_helper_now/). The replacement recommended in the linked Reddit discussion is [Steam Economy Enhancer userscript](https://github.com/Nuklon/Steam-Economy-Enhancer). N.B. It must be installed through Tampermonkey (or Violentmonkey), but is open source and thus far, well received in the community.

It also works well on Firefox. Source: Personal experience of unloading all of my Steam cards in the last five minutes...

Comment: Came back to this post because I was having this problem again. Glad to see this exists! One click sell my inventory of 1000 cards is far less painful than the alternative.

Answer (score 3):

No, not through the steam market anyway. With the market you have to sell them all individually.

You might be able to trade them in bulk for a couple of items (like CS:GO skins) that you can then put on the market quicker.

Answer (score 3):

There’s actually a built-in way to do this now.

1. Go to "Badges" (on top navigation where your username is in the middle)
2. Pick the Game you have a lot of cards for
3. Hit "Sell These Cards on the Market"
   [image: Screenshot showing the Steam UI for selling cards in bulk]

Answer (score 2):

There are actually bots in steam that buys trading cards.

One good example: http://steamcommunity.com/id/CardExchange

The buying rates may differ from one bot to another. You can search through steam for more examples.

If you are looking to sell for steam wallet (steam market transaction), unfortunately that is not possible.