# How can I turn off all the Steam Inventory/Trading Cards/Community stuff?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

Steam has a 'trading card'-social-media *thing*. I don't really get it, and I have zero interest in it.

As far as I can tell, it basically serves to clutter up the Steam interface, and constantly barrage you about new junk in your 'Steam Inventory' that I frankly don't care about.

Is there anyway to disable the whole thing? Maybe I just hate (certain types) of fun, but I frankly completely fail to understand why I should care about the whole affair at all. It would make the steam client a lot nicer if I never had to see any of it again.

There doesn't seem to be any way to just delete cards from your steam inventory.

Comment: Dunno about removing the Community/Inventory from the Steam client (there may be a skin for steam that hides them at least), but if you just wanna be rid of cards quickly, have a look at the answers [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192060/any-way-to-mass-sell-all-my-steam-trading-cards), you can sell them in bulk on the market and make back a little Steam Wallet cash, or trade them to a bot in exchange for items for games you *do* care about).

Comment: related question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302563/how-to-automatically-mark-steam-notifications-as-read

Comment: You're not alone, OP!

Answer (score 5):

To piggyback on what @Nitrous Oxide (Awesome name) Said... You cannot stop/turn off the Steam Trading Card system.  They are earned by playing games you have that has the Trading Card System enabled and random events.

I understand it can be quite frustrating at times to receive two-four cards at once and have to view-acknowledge them in order to make the notification disappear BUT you could simply ignore the entire system and horde cards for some time.  Eventually you could trade in sets of them for new quirky badges, backgrounds, and experience for your Steam Profile.  OR you could "bite the bullet" and enter the Trading Card community once a month or so and sell all the cards you have for pennies on the dollar to eventually be able to buy something you want.

I hope this helps out a bit.

Comment: +1 for saving them up to buy better stuff.

Comment: Can't just "ignore" the system when you want to know if you have new messages or turns... but nope, it's just more item notifications.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no. The Steam trading cards are rewarded to you when you spend a specific amount of time in a game. If you really want to get rid of the cards put them on the community market or trade them to someone who wants them.

Answer (score -1):

Create a second Steam account, and trade all your inventory crap to it every so often.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).