# How to automatically mark Steam notifications as read?

Tags: steam

I'm sure that this is possible as a "trading card idler" program [ArchiSteamFarm](https://github.com/JustArchi/ArchiSteamFarm) can [mark item notifications as read](https://github.com/JustArchiNET/ArchiSteamFarm/wiki/Configuration#botbehaviour) (I don't know how the feature works when you're playing a game instead of "idling"):

> `DismissInventoryNotifications` - `bool` type with default value of `false`.
>   Every card drop triggers inventory notification - Steam notification
>   telling you that you received new items. This can get annoying pretty
>   fast, and serves little to no purpose, therefore ASF offers dismissing
>   those notifications automatically. When you enable this option, ASF
>   will automatically dismiss all notifications related to new items
>   being received - this also includes items you obtained through trading
>   and other ways. Of course, this option affects only inventory
>   notifications, so all other notification types, e.g. profile comments
>   notifications, will stay intact.

Other notification categories on Steam:

- comments
- chat
- invites
- gifts

Currently Steam doesn't offer an option to disable notifications globally. It is always unclear whether I've receive a message from a friend or a trading card drop worth of 0.01$.

[image: notification icon]

Comment: This question is not a duplicate as I'm not asking for a way to disable notifications altogether.

Comment: If you're talking about those little annoying notification windows popping up every now and then.. yes, you can disable them globally.

Comment: @dly: No, I'm not talking about "announcements" (settings > interface > notify me about....). See the screenshot in my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aforementioned ASF [can be run in paused state](https://github.com/JustArchiNET/ArchiSteamFarm/wiki/FAQ#i-dont-want-asf-to-farm-any-games-by-default-yet-i-want-to-use-extra-asf-features-is-this-possible), persistently on the background and [set to start when you launch your computer](https://superuser.com/questions/184556/add-a-program-to-startup-in-windows-7):

> **I don't want ASF to farm any games by default, yet I want to use extra
>   ASF features. Is this possible?**
>
> Yes, you can set `Paused` bot config property to `true` in order to launch
>   ASF with paused cards farming module, then you can make use of extra
>   ASF features, such as `GamesPlayedWhileIdle`.

Then add [`DismissInventoryNotifications`](https://github.com/JustArchiNET/ArchiSteamFarm/wiki/Configuration#botbehaviour) (`8`) to your bot configuration file. `RejectInvalidFriendInvites` (`1`) automatically rejects all friend invites from "non-bot" accounts (i.e. all by default). You can use both features by setting `BotBehaviour` to `9`; a basic [ASF config](https://justarchinet.github.io/ASF-WebConfigGenerator) for clarification:

```
{
  "Enabled": true,
  "IdleRefundableGames": false,
  "BotBehaviour": 9,
  "OnlineStatus": 0,
  "SteamLogin": "user",
  "SteamPassword": "password"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ASF manages this because the author built that feature into it. It listens for notification events from the Steam server itself the same as the client does when it's connected. When it gets a notification it checks if it's for a card drop, and "opens" it or otherwise does something to tell Steam the user has seen that notification.

The closest thing I know of that can easily be done is [use a custom skin](https://github.com/l3laze/NoNotifications) to keep the notification bubbles from popping up by limiting them to 0 seconds and a maximum of 0 notifications in the stack at a time.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to use your custom skin — I moved `steam.styles` file to `~\Program Files (x86)\Steam\skins` (I also tried creating a folder for the skin) and the skin doesn't appear in Steam client, I only have "default skin" option available in the interface settings. In any case, you should add installation instructions to your repository.

Comment: @user598527: Excellent point, sorry about that! Just pushed an update to the readme with installation directions including default Steam installation directories for each platform and the skin directories (because it's different on Mac). Also includes DIY directions for those who would rather not download it.

I think the issue is that the steam.styles file needs to be in a resource folder inside the skin folder, like `../Steam/skins/Skin Folder/resource/steam.styles`. Which also points out that I forgot the resource folder in the skin...lol -- sorry; also fixed that with the update.

Comment: I'm sorry, but after updating there still is no custom skin in the dropdown menu. Are you able to select the skin?

Comment: Sorry; I've been bedridden with bronchitis for a few days now. Still screwed up, but almost clear [cognitively] again. The update above was also messed up =\\ -- the steam.styles file is supposed to be at `../Steam/skins/Skin Folder/resource/styles/steam.styles`, but I was too messed up at the time and should've waited to fix that. Updated again, and tested the GitHub Clone/Download to ensure it's working. Sorry, again.

Please PM me if you have any other issues with this; don't want to take over the thread any more than we have already, lol.

Comment: The skin can now be selected, thank you for actively responding to questions and fixing the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I forgot to test your skin with notifications and unfortunately they show normally at least at the time.

Comment: No problem. Valve has been making *a lot* of quiet changes and I think they've begun switching the client to work like the new friends/chat webapp with the latest. For the friends/chat this killed skins because part of it is loaded from the web each run and the only way to style it is to open the dev tools (which may no longer be enabled) and use a script to change the UI *every time*. Valve could automate that , but don't seem concerned as of yet. There are [manual directions](https://redd.it/7p2mkv) you can try but they're old unfortunately. My PC is dead(-ish) or I'd try myself. Sorry :(